# TypeError: req.getConnection is not a function

Tags: mysql, node.js, api, express, crud

**strong text**I'm trying to create my first CRUD with Mysql, Node js and Express.js following a tutorial.
The problem is, in the video this code works, but in my visual give the error aboyt getConnection is not a function.

If anyones can help, I'll apreciate.

**Server.js**

```
const express = require("express");
    const mysql = require("mysql");
    const myconn = require("express-myconnection");
    const routes = require("./routes");
    
    const app = express();
    
    const serverPort = process.env.PORT || 9000;
    const dbOptions = {
      host: "localhost",
      user: "3306",
      password: "123456",
      database: "catalog",
    };
    
    //server running
    app.listen(serverPort, () => {
      console.log(`App listening at ${serverPort}`);
    });
    
    //routes
    app.get("/", (req, res) => {
      res.send("welcome to my API");
    });
    app.use("/phones", routes);
```

**Routes.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const routes = express.Router();
const myconn = require("express-myconnection");

routes.get("/", (req, res) => {
  req.getConnection((err, conn) => {
    if (err) return res.send(err);

    conn.query("SELECT * FROM phones", (err, rows) => {
      if (err) return res.send(err);
      res.json(rows);
    });
  });
});

module.exports = routes;
```

**UPDATE** : solved.

IT WAS A POINT after catalog and I didn't write the port correctly!!!!!

Comment: Read docs https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-myconnection#usage , you need to add something like `app.use(myconn(mysql, dbOptions, 'single');` before routes

Comment: I trried but now the terminal is in a loop and still can't acces to the Data base, 

// 20210523213234
// http://localhost:9000/phones

{
  "code": "PROTOCOL_ENQUEUE_AFTER_FATAL_ERROR",
  "fatal": false
}

Comment: Update your question with actual code

Comment: I think your dbOptions are incorrect. User is 3306? It's default mysql port.

Comment: Yes i didn't have a port correctly and the point after catalog. 
Thank you very much for your help, after 2 hour others eyes can see better things